# Three-finger tap lookup multiple words

Tags: macos, high-sierra, gesture, look-up

Is there a way to get the three-finger tap (AKA Look up & data detectors) to include more than a single word?  I've tried selecting the desired text, then three-finger tapping, but to no avail.

This would be helpful with proper names (cities and people).

[image]